# How can I make the Dispatch_after function in Objective-C from Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I just found the function that uses Dispatch_after in Swift. I'd like to make it into Objective-C though, I don't know how to do it.

```swift
func delay(interval: TimeInterval, closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
     DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + interval) {
          closure()
     }
}
```

```swift
delay(interval: 1) { 
    print("Hi!")
}
```

Comment: Xcode will suggest code snippet for you, when you type `dispatchafter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
- (void)delayWithInterval:(NSTimeInterval)interval block:(void (^)(void))block
{
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, interval * NSEC_PER_SEC),
                   dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
        block();
    });
}
```

Assuming this method is in the same class (as in Swift code), you call it like this:

```
[self delayWithInterval:1 block:^
{
    NSLog(@"Hi!");
}];
```

Comment: How can I write inside of "block:" which I wanna add some actions?